# Download Latest File from SharePoint Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have very little idea on sharepoint. Need a start,how to access the share point site and download the latest file avilable in a particular folder.

I am using ASP.Net/C#.Net and Visual Studio 2008 to download file.

What is requirement means any particular libraray/update/pathes?

How can i get to know path of webservice ? (I only know the direct URL)

Is it possible to access the metadata of the file.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: If u have direct URL then what is the problem? and which api u r using for download?

Comment: @Rasa I want this activity automated through program. To download the file and save it to some local folder. I am using C#.net i don't know which library will work in that.

Comment: I am doing the same thing what u want to do ..I am configuring sharepoint the lastest update url and then reading the manifest fron application for URL and once u get the URL then u can use BITS to download.

Comment: @Rasa I dont know from where to start, I mean which webservice to connect to.Any idea how i can find or only programmers of the sharepoint site can tell me that???

Comment: If u have not configured sharepoint then its not a very easy task..we took one month to configure that. So better u follow some tutorial for some days instead of directly jumping to actual implementation. Because Sharepoint and app connection is always errorprone and u cant really debug for "what the hell going wrong" so better go slowly and steady :-)

Comment: @Rasa Thats why started little POC on basics. Hope to come up with solution in couple of days.

Answer (score 1):

I found this on a web search at some point. This is what I ended up using.

```
var remotefile = @"https://pathtoremotefile";
var localfile = @"C:\pathtolocalfile";
using(WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
    // or new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user","pass","domain");
    wc.DownloadFile(remotefile,localfile);
}
```